# Play same base64 data concurrently multiple times

Tags: html, audio, base64

I am making an all-client-side audio/music editor. I have created a few tones mathematically that are stored as base64 in the `<audio>` src-attribute. I can play DIFFERENT tones at the same time BUT, I can only play ONE instance of ONE specific tone at the same time.

For example clicking the key to play C like crazy will sound very awkward since the C that was playing gets stopped and the new C starts. I would like there to be possibility to play several C tones at the same time!

Now I guess this could be made by having by simple copying the audio element (one or more times) and make the keypress, sort of, cycle through them. For example if the first C tone is playing and the key to play C is clicked, then play the second C audio element, and so on and so forth.

That would work... but since I am using base64 in the source I would also have to have that copied.

```
<audio id="C1"><source src="data:audio/wav;base64,audio_data"></source></audio>
<audio id="C2"><source src="data:audio/wav;base64,audio_data"></source></audio>
```

If "audio_data" would be really long then the html would become humongous and also I think that the browser would not understand that both are actually the exactly same data, so it would be come very unoptimized.

**So to the concrete question:** Is there a way to play the same base64 data several times at the same time without the need of copying the whole src-attribute with the base64 string in it? (Since my application is all-client so I have not the ability to save the data to a sound-file on a server)

See a simple example. It might not work in other browsers than Firefox because I have not tested:
https://jsfiddle.net/tx3hpptL/